# Problem with File command (ERROR: cannot open 'whatever' (No such file or directory))

Tags: command-line

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on both desktop and laptop.

I've been using Ubuntu for a couple of years and recently took the courage to buy a book about commands in Linux, but I've found a problem that has been bugging me for days now.

The book presents the file command written on the terminal as:

```
$ file picture.jpg
```

But when I type `file whatever` the message `ERROR: cannot open 'whatever' (No such file or directory)` appears.

I've tried to type the file with and without the extension. I've tried on both PCs, even naming a `.jpg` file `picture` to replicate the results shown in the book. No results.

Am I writing the command wrongly? Is this book outdated for Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Comment: Try using tab completion about half-way through the file name (e.g. `file whate{tab}{tab}`) see if that outputs anything

Comment: I tried the command "file picture.jpg" first with the file on the "Documents" directory and then on "Home". Checked the working directory both times with "pwd" and it was "/home/user"

Comment: press tab after typing `file picture.jp` see if there's any output

Comment: Now it worked! Thanks! Any idea why I couldn't make it work before? 

By the way, should I change the working directory every time I want to use the file command or is there any way to make it work regardless of the directory the file is into?

Comment: To make it work regardless of working directory use a **Non-Relative path** (such as `file /home/Candren/picture.jpg`) (Like how I made it look like a textbook?)

Comment: You're welcome! Just make sure to mark the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press tab right before the end of the command (i.e. `file picture.jp{TAB}` where it says `{TAB}` press tab)